# MKV file in React Player, display missing problem

Tags: html, reactjs, mkv

Here is my code and I have two different mkv files. One of the mkv files is being played without any problem in chrome but the other one does not have a display!
Is it because encoder or stuff like that? any solutions?

```
             <ReactPlayer
                ref={playerRef}
                playing
                controls={true}
                url={`videos/${readyList[currentEpisodeIndex]}.mkv`}
                width="90%"
                height="55rem"
                config={{
                }}
              />
```

Comment: You can try to add `type="video/x-matroska"`

Comment: @Rguarascia Thank you but didnt work